# Can't connect to REMIX via private geth chain on my vps

Tags: remix

I'm running geth on my vps.
Trying to connect to it via REMIX,

On REMIX,
in "Environment",
I chose "web3 provider",

in "Web3 Provider Endpoint",
I put
"mydomain.net:8565"

but I cant connect...

Answer (score 0):

I chose http REMIX and works fine